# Why does my new garbage disposal drain poorly unless turned on?

Tags: garbage-disposal

I've installed a new garbage disposal and noticed a problematic behavior: the new garbage disposal drains very poorly, unless it's turned on. I can barely even wash my hands without noticing a little water accumulation. When doing dishes I have to turn it on over 5 times to prevent undesired water build-up. What to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to show a picture of the drain plumbing from the garbage disposal.

Comment: I was about to but the question got closed.

Comment: Hey do you mind re-opening the question. I tried posting a new one to attach the image but he tells me that  a similar one already exists.

Comment: Voted to re-open, (editing the picture in here is the correct way to get that done) but could you try another picture that shows the whole of the drain from the disposal to the wall, not mostly hidden behind the disposal?

Comment: Closed questions can always be edited, @Ya. Deleted ones not so much, but you can always edit your closed question. As a matter of fact, the blue banner that tells you it's closed contains an _extra_ link for you to click to edit it in an attempt to get it reopened. You've been on SO and [unix.se] long enough, you should know that - it's all the same system...

Comment: The reason I tried closing this one because I've opened another one: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/284629/why-does-my-new-garbage-disposal-drain-poorly-unless-turned-on with more documentation. Never had to deal with this because I've never had anyone close out a question on me within a few hours just because they didn't get the requested info. Anyway to ease the confusion I propose that we delete this question and keep the other one open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the new rubber 'flap' is too 'hard' and won't permit enough flow through. Broke it in a bit and it drains better now.

Comment: Are you talking about the upper rubber "flap" piece that goes in the sink drain?

Comment: Yes, edited for clarification

Comment: Interesting. I've never run into this issue, but I'll definitely keep it in mind should I ever have difficulties like this in the future. Glad you got it resolved! Please come back and click the check mark next to this answer to indicate that this was the solution to the problem. I think the system will make you wait 24 or 48 hours before allowing you do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of installing a garbage disposal, which drains lower than the sink drain did, without adjusting the plumbing into the drain pipes, and then expecting water to flow uphill into the drain.

Correction is typically either "don't have a disposal" (easy) or "break open the wall and put in a new sanitary Tee somewhat lower" (hard.) You can put a cleanout plug in the old sanitary Tee drain opening.