# new garbage disposal with the same plumbing drains slowly unless turned on

Tags: garbage-disposal

I've installed a new garbage disposal and noticed a problematic behavior: the new garbage disposal drains very poorly, unless it's turned on. I can barely even wash my hands without noticing a little water accumulation. When doing dishes I have to turn it on over 5 times to prevent undesired water build-up. What to do? See the picture of the plumbing below.
[image]

[image]
Note: Here is my first attempt at this question, I was asked to attach a picture but the question got closed before I had a chance to do so. Also the answer suggested in the original question does not apply. Please don't close this one as a duplicate.
[new garbage disposal drains poorly unless turned on](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/284629/new-garbage-disposal-drains-poorly-unless-turned-on)

Comment: No it doesn't. I was asked to attach a picture but it was closed before I was able to do so.

Comment: Can you post a picture showing the pipes behind the disposal?  It is we are not there and cannot see everything.  It looks like it is high enough, but there might be something we are missing/can't see behind.

Comment: When your queston is closed for more detail, you edit the detail into the question so it can get re-opened. Asking the same question again wastes everybody's time. As already noted there, this picture fails to show the important parts of the plumbing in question.

Comment: @crip659 Added additional picture